# plotting equations with restricted domains in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, interactive

there. 
Im building an shiny app thats plots some functions. The user can modify the parameters.  The problem appears when I have a restricted function,  specially when its related to x. This is one example:

Sliders:

```
sliderInput("th19",
    HTML("$$ \\theta_1 $$"),
    min = 1,
    max = 10,
    value = 2)
sliderInput("thB9",
    HTML("$$ \\theta_b $$"),
    min = 1,
    max = 10,
    value = 2)
sliderInput("vthB9",
   HTML("$$ \\vartheta_b $$"),
   min = 1,
   max = 20,
   value = 2)
```

Plot:

```
mForm9.1 <- as.formula("Y ~ vthB9 + th19*(x - thB9)")
mExpr9.1 <- mForm9.1[[3]]

output$Curve9 <- renderPlot({
    th19 <- input$th19
    vthB9 <- input$vthB9
    thB9 <- input$thB9

    eval(call("curve", mExpr9.1, col = 2, ylab = "", main =
               expression(vartheta[b] + theta[1]*(x - theta[b]))))

    },  height = 400, width = 600)

    mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
            tabPanel("Gráfico", plotOutput("Curve9"))
   ))
```

What happens here is that when 'x' is bigger than 'vthB9', the equation resumes itself to only 'vthB9', and this is only one of the cases I have. Anybody knows what to do?

*Hope I have been clear

*Im using `flexdashboard`, this is why the shiny might seen a little different

Comment: Could you elaborate your question more?

Comment: Imagine you have y = x^2 + b, when x in less or equal to b, and y = x^2 when x is bigger then b (simple, ficticious example). I can only plot one thing, because i can't set the domain restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are possibly multiple ways to plot a piecewise function in `R`. I am going to suggest probably the easiest way of doing it **in this case**:

We first define the piecewise function, say, `fun`

```
fun <- function(x) { 
      ifelse(test = x <= vthB9, 
             yes = vthB9 + th19 * (x - thB9),
             no = vthB9) 
    }
```

which we then pass to `curve`

```
curve(expr = fun, from = 0, to = 10, col = 2, ylab = "", 
      main = expression(vartheta[b] + theta[1] * (x - theta[b])))
```

`curve` is going to input a **vector** as a parameter to the function `fun`. The usual `if-else` statements are not going to work because they can test only one value at a time - unless we write a for-loop or vectorise it somehow with a function `Vectorize`. Instead of that, we pick `ifelse` which is already vectorized.

Since you have used a `shiny` tag I've prepared a `shiny` app instead of  `flexdashboard` :)

---

**Full shiny example**

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel( 
          sliderInput("th19",
                      HTML("&theta; <sub>1</sub>"),
                      min = 1,
                      max = 10,
                      value = 2),
          sliderInput("thB9",
                      HTML("&theta; <sub>b</sub>"),
                      min = 1,
                      max = 10,
                      value = 2),
          sliderInput("vthB9",
                      HTML("&thetasym; <sub>b</sub>"),
                      min = 1,
                      max = 20,
                      value = 2)
          ),
          mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                        tabPanel("Gráfico", plotOutput("Curve9")))
          ))
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {

      output$Curve9 <- renderPlot({
        th19 <- input$th19
        vthB9 <- input$vthB9
        thB9 <- input$thB9

        # Define a piece wise function
        fun <- function(x) { 
          ifelse(test = x <= vthB9, 
                 yes = vthB9 + th19 * (x - thB9),
                 no = vthB9) 
        }
        # x-axis goes now from 0 to 10
        curve(expr = fun, from = 0, to = 10, col = 2, ylab = "", 
              main = expression(vartheta[b] + theta[1] * (x - theta[b])))

      },  height = 400, width = 600)

    }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi there! I adapted it to flexdashboard and worked just fine! thank you very much :)